# Why doesn't my makefile with include header work?

Tags: c++, makefile, jvmti

I have the following makefile (for c++)

```
LDLIBS=$(shell root-config --libs)
INCLUDE= -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include            \
         -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin     \


foo: foo.o
        $(CXX) -shared -fPIC $(LDLIBS) $(INCLUDE) -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

foo.cpp has the following includes

```
#include <jvmti.h>
```

If I run the `"g++ -shared -fPIC -I..."` command manually, it'll produce the `foo.o` as expected.

But when I run `make`, I'll get this error

```
$ make                                                                                                                                 
c++    -c -o foo.o foo.cpp                                                                                                 
lib_track_npe.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'jvmti.h' file not found                                                                                  
#include <jvmti.h>                                                                                                                             
         ^                                                                                                                                     
1 error generated.                                                                                                                             
make: *** [foo.o] Error 1
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong in the makefile?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the command: `pwd` when you type it just after entering `g++ ... ` manually?

Comment: pwd is the current directory (where foo.cpp) is located. Please not that in my `-I`, I specified an absolute path. Hence, it shouldn't matter where I call it

Comment: Yes it should. Manually you pass -I.. which means that the parent directory is in search path

Comment: Ooh, actually that `...` (ie., ellipsis ) was meant as "etc" ;)

Comment: Oh I got it. So, in your original makefile, I guess you just declared wrongly your rule. I guess it should be: `foo.o : foo.cpp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit `make` rule for building `.o` targets from `.cpp` sources does not use the `INCLUDE` variable. `INCLUDE` is not a standard variable used by default `make` rules. Your `Makefile` is dependent on the default make rules in order to build `.o` targets from `.cpp` sources.

The correct `make` variable for specifying preprocessor options is `CPPFLAGS`:

```
CPPFLAGS= -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include            \
         -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin     \
```

Additionally, your explicit `make` rule for linking `foo` from `foo.o` specifies all these `-I` optionals. Unfortunately, that accomplishes absolutely nothing, whatsoever. `-I` is used only when compiling `.cpp` sources. The `-I` option is not used at all, when linking, and is effectively ignored when linking. You should simply remove the `$(INCLUDE)` from your link command, without even replacing it with `$(CPPFLAGS)`. It only causes confusion.

Comment: Oooh, I see. I, as a makefile novice, thought I could "declare" any variable (which is called INCLUDE in this case) and reference it!

Comment: You can declare and reference any variable you wish. But if you need to rely on default rules, declaring only the variables that are actually used by the default rules is going to accomplish anything useful. The default rule used here does not use `INCLUDE`. You can declare it, and use it however you wish, but the default rule will not use it.

Comment: Hmm, so how do I make it use it?

Comment: Define your own rule for building `.cpp` from `.o`, which can use whatever you want it to use. Just like you defined the rule to link foo from foo.o. In fact, existing frameworks based on make, such as GNU automake, will generate their own custom build rules, overriding make's default rules.